How do ISPs redirect your DNS to their own DNS server?
Let's say you set your DNS as one of the public DNS servers such as Cloudflare 1.1.1.1, Google 8.8.8.8. However, your ISP instead redirects those IP addresses to their own DNS server. So, how did they did it and how to prevent?

This an actual problem you face because unless you use your ISP for DNS they can’t do what you describe in most cases. Do you live in a region with high regulatory rules surrounding internet connectivity?

Does How can I overcome my ISP's DNS redirection when DoH is blocked? contain the information you are looking for?


So, how did they did it

There are several ways – for example, the ISP might internally set up IP routes so that packets for specific IP addresses would take a different path; e.g. if the ISP's fake DNS server literally has 8.8.8.8/32 set up as one of its IP addresses, it will be "closer" than the real 8.8.8.8, and the network will prefer the shorter path to the fake server than the longer path to the real one.
IP routing is already what an ISP's infrastructure does the entire time, so defining one additional route is practically zero effort.
Another method is to have their routers rewrite the IP packets themselves – DNAT, the exact same way your home router does "port forwarding" to internal addresses. It's less efficient, but it still takes just a single firewall rule to say "any packets with destination 8.8.8.8 should be changed to 192.168.1.53", and it could be made more precise e.g. by only redirecting DNS but not HTTP.

how to prevent?

Try less popular servers; some ISPs only redirect 8.8.8.8 and nothing else. (You can even run your own DNS server on the cheapest VPS you find.)
Instead of plain-text DNS try either DNS-over-TLS or DNS-over-HTTPS. Often ISPs are more hesitant to intercept those as TLS/HTTPS makes that very obvious.

DNS has zero privacy or authentication built-in, so anyone between your device and the DNS server can redirect your DNS queries however they want.
You can resolve this by using DNS over HTTPS (DoH), which requires the DNS server to verify that it is actually the service you expect. You have to configure it on each device, like:

Windows
Set up Android/iOS
Configure DoH on your browser

If your ISP blocks DoH services (very uncommon), then you may need to use a VPN to send everything in a way that your ISP can't see.
